# Making changes to DNS (bind) through git, how make it?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

What is the correct way to change the entries in the Bind zone file and apply it through Gitlab CI/runner?

Comment: Use Ansible, store playbooks and support files in the git repo. Hopefully, sooner or later you'll find out that those playbooks could perform more than just managing DNS records, but also other aspects of systems that those records are going to be used for.

Comment: I forgot to write, the essence of the task is to give different users access to change their records, as part of the DR process, sed and awk only comes to mind.

Comment: No, don't! Updating text zone files (correctly and securely) will be a great pain. Use `nsupdate` with personal TSIG keys, or even Kerberos, and adequate update policy, it is the only secure and reliable way to do it in BIND. What a coincidence, this is exactly what [community.general.nsupdate module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nsupdate_module.html) expects (no, not a coincidence, its just people who use Ansible know right ways to do things).